# coverage.py does not cover script if py.test executes it from another directory

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py

I got a python script which takes command line arguments, working with some files.
I'm writing succeeding tests with `py.test` putting this script through its paces, executing it with `subprocess.call`.

Now I want to analyze code coverage with `coverage.py`.
Coverage, when used via the `pytest-cov` plugin (which has subprocess-handling built-in), **does not see/cover my script** when it is called from a temporary testing directory created with `py.test`'s `tmpdir` fixture.
Coverage **does see** my script when it's called in the directory it resides in (and the filename argument points to a remote path).

In both situations, my **tests pass**! Coverage 3.6, pytest-2.3.5, pytest-cov 1.6, all from PyPi.

Question: How can I get coverage to recognize my script even if it's executed in another directory? Is this a bug in coverage, or something which is just not possible to do? Would be surprised if the latter, after all, `tmpdir` is a stock mechanism of py.test...

**Minimal example:**

I got a script `my_script.py` which just echoes the contents of a file `arg_file.txt` supplied via command-line argument. In two different tests, this is once called in a `tmpdir`, and once in the script's location. Both tests pass, but the in the tmpdir test, I get no coverage information!

Test run:

```
~/pytest_experiment$ py.test -s
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov
collected 2 items 

tests/test_in_scriptdir.py 
set_up: In directory /tmp/pytest-52/test_10
Running in directory /home/cbuchner/pytest_experiment
Command: ./my_script.py /tmp/pytest-52/test_10/arg_file.txt
--Contents of arg_file.txt--

.
tests/test_in_tmpdir.py 
set_up: In directory /tmp/pytest-52/test_11
Running in directory /tmp/pytest-52/test_11
Command: /home/cbuchner/pytest_experiment/my_script.py arg_file.txt
--Contents of arg_file.txt--

.

================================= 2 passed in 0.06 seconds =================================
```

Coverage:

```
~/pytest_experiment$ py.test --cov=my_script.py tests/test_in_scriptdir.py=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov
collected 1 items 

tests/test_in_scriptdir.py .
--------------------- coverage: platform linux2, python 2.7.4-final-0 ----------------------
Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover
-------------------------------
my_script       3      0   100%

================================= 1 passed in 0.09 seconds =================================
~/pytest_experiment$ py.test --cov=my_script.py tests/test_in_tmpdir.py=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov
collected 1 items 

tests/test_in_tmpdir.py .Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.

--------------------- coverage: platform linux2, python 2.7.4-final-0 ----------------------
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------

================================= 1 passed in 0.09 seconds =================================
```

The files are here: https://gist.github.com/bilderbuchi/6412754

**Edit:** Interstingly, when running the coverage tests with `-s`, too, there's more curious output - coverage warns that `No data was collected`, when obviously it was collected, and in the `tmpdir` test warns that `Module my_script.py was never imported.`??

```
~/pytest_experiment$ py.test -s --cov=my_script.py tests/test_in_scriptdir.py
=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov
collected 1 items 

tests/test_in_scriptdir.py 
set_up: In directory /tmp/pytest-63/test_10
Running in directory /home/cbuchner/pytest_experiment
Command: ./my_script.py /tmp/pytest-63/test_10/arg_file.txt
--Contents of arg_file.txt--

Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
.
--------------------- coverage: platform linux2, python 2.7.4-final-0 ----------------------
Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover
-------------------------------
my_script       3      0   100%

================================= 1 passed in 0.09 seconds =================================
~/pytest_experiment$ py.test -s --cov=my_script.py tests/test_in_tmpdir.py=================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: cov
collected 1 items 

tests/test_in_tmpdir.py 
set_up: In directory /tmp/pytest-64/test_10
Running in directory /tmp/pytest-64/test_10
Command: /home/cbuchner/pytest_experiment/my_script.py arg_file.txt
--Contents of arg_file.txt--

Coverage.py warning: Module my_script.py was never imported.
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
Coverage.py warning: Module my_script.py was never imported.
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
.Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.

--------------------- coverage: platform linux2, python 2.7.4-final-0 ----------------------
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------

================================= 1 passed in 0.09 seconds =================================
```

Comment: Sorry for non-answer. But it sounds to me that you will have to look inside py.test to see speciality of tmpdir fixture. If it in some sort of context manager, coverage is getting called after it exits (or something like that).

Comment: Thanks. I'm already in contact with the coverage developer, I'll post a summary once we've gotten to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Christoph if you are still interested in getting this to work with pytest-cov feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/schlamar/pytest-cov. I'm the new maintainer of pytest-cov and might be able to help.

Comment: @schlamar thanks, but I have already worked around that issue on my side (see my answer below). While I normally would (properly) open a bug report about this, I currently don't have time to care about this and test it again and post a repro procedure, sorry.

Comment: @schlamar I just checked, and I can still repro using the procedure above, but I'm not even sure anymore if this is actually a slight user error when using coverage to cover stuff called by `subprocess`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem of relative paths confusing coverage when the measured script is run from another directory. Coverage result files ended up in that directory, instead of the root directory of the project.

To solve this, I stopped using `pytest-cov`, and used pure `coverage` instead. I used full paths instead of relative paths wherever relevant.

So, e.g. 
define the environment variable necessary to enable subprocess coverage via `export COVERAGE_PROCESS_START=/full/path/to/.coveragerc`. 
In the `.coveragerc`, the coverage result file is specified via

```
     [run]
     data_file = /full/path/to/.coverage
```

and any `--source` and `--include` options should use full paths, too.
Then it was possible to get correct coverage measurement.

Comment: I am afraid that this is not a generally acceptable answer as this cannot work if you have continuous integration, we need a proper solution.

Comment: what about CI precludes you from using full paths?

Comment: @Christoph: You often don't control (nor should you have to control) the exact location where your sources are built/extracted (whatever build step is relevant). Hence the need to rely on relative paths.

Comment: Point taken. Although, you can get at least partly around that by working with environment variables holding full paths that you generate on the fly, via `os.path.abspath()`. In any case, I don't know if this is even still a problem, my old code I used this in doesn't have full paths in `.covragerc`.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the same issue when calling "py.test --cov ..." from tox. I found a hint on this page: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/ even though it does not mention this explicitly. Using "--develop" for tox will make sure that coverage data gathering is called from the same directory as coverage analysis.
This section in *tox.ini* made it work for me to have a test environment for coverage:

```
[tox]
envlist = ...,py34,cov

[testenv:cov]
# necessary to make cov find the .coverage file
# see http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/
usedevelop = true
commands = py.test --cov=<MODULE_NAME>
deps = pytest pytest-cov
```

Comment: This is so far the best answer which just helped me save another hour. Thumbs up for you.

Comment: This makes the testing a bit less thorough, since you are no testing against the dist generated from your setup.py.

Comment: This is because your library name doesn't match the module name.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with tox is to set the `PYTHONPATH` in `tox.ini`:

`[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
commands =
    pytest --cov=<your package>
    - codecov`

Answer (score 0):

according to this blog:
https://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2017/01/pytest-cov-collects-no-data-on-travis/

You should add all the `__init__.py` files in `tests` folder! This solution works for me.