# Coverage.py warning: No data was collected

Tags: django, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am having problem on testing my django application. It passes all the tests but coverage.py doesn't give any report about the coverage. Any luck on this? Thanks

Comment: What is the command you used to run your tests with coverage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573542/coverage-py-does-not-cover-script-if-py-test-executes-it-from-another-directory

Comment: I used coverage run --source='.' manage.py test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287721/coverage-py-warning-no-data-was-collected-no-data-collected)

Answer (score 5):

The [coverage docs](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html) say the following:

> “No data was collected (no-data-collected)”
>
> Coverage.py ran your program, but didn’t measure any lines as executed. This could be because you asked to measure only modules that never ran, or for other reasons.

That means that your config needs some tweaking. In my case I forgot to glob the directory I specified in my `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
include = my_app/*
```

Have a look at the command you're running the tests with and your config files. There may be some directives working against each other.