# Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)

Tags: python, django, pytest, coverage.py, test-coverage

I am trying to find the coverage using coverage module for a django project but gets

```
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

My project folder has src and tests folders.

When I run

```
coverage run -m pytest && coverage report
```

It produces a report with 100% coverage with the list of files inside the tests folder.
Whereas when I run

```
coverage run --source=src -m pytest && coverage report
```

it says

```
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
No data to report.
```

When I try to give the `source=src` or `include=src` in the `.coveragerc` also the same warning occurs. The tests passes for all the above cases.

I want the coverage of the src folder.
Is it because I am missing some path setting?

Comment: Perhaps you are not running code from the src folder? Add --debug=trace to the coverage run line. It will print information about each file executed, whether it is traced, and if not, why not.

Comment: try to replace src with an actual path. It should point to a folder and not a file

Answer (score 40):

`coverage` (used by `pytest-cov`) needs the tests folder to contain an `__init__.py` before it will collect any data.

I added `__init__.py` to the tests folder and then coverage collected the data as expected.

Refer to http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2017/01/pytest-cov-collects-no-data-on-travis/

Comment: Judging by the upvotes this seems to be a solution for some people, but in my case pytest-cov works just fine with no `__init__.py` files in my `tests` folder.

Comment: This depends on your package layout. Common practice is to keep tests outside of application code, and in this case you don't want `__init__.py` files in your test directories. If you are using the same name for test modules or have "inline" tests, then you would want `__init__.py` files in your test directories (See [pytest best practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code)).

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue and the problem was with the path I was running the tests.

**What is working now:**

Structure

```
~/Projects/ProjectName
├── manage.py
├── tests
├── src
│   ├── app_one
├── .coveragerc
```

Command:

```
~/Projects/ProjectName$ coverage run manage.py test
```

and my .coveragerc:

```
[run]
include = */src/*
omit = *migrations*, *tests*
plugins = django_coverage_plugin
```

Comment: where is .coveragerc file?

Comment: in the ProjectName folder...will update the structure above

Comment: and where do you run pytest now exactly?

Comment: What is manage.py?

Comment: Manage.py in Django is a command-line utility that works similar to the django-admin command

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you're not specifying which dir to get coverage from.

You can specify that in the `.coveragerc` file or on the command line:

```
pytest tests -v --cov-report term --cov-report html:htmlcov --cov-report xml --cov-fail-under=90 --cov=<the-dir-to-colect-coverage-from>
```

If you desire you can only execute `pytest tests` and add `pytest` args on `pytest.ini` at your project root:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -v --cov-report term --cov-report html:htmlcov --cov-report xml --cov-fail-under=<coverage-percentage-desired> --cov=<the-dir-to-colect-coverage-from>
```

**Bonus:**

If you want to omit files from the coverage you can add a `.coveragerc` file on your project root:

```
[run]
omit =
    # omit everything in the folder
    proj-ab/api/confs/
    # omit file
    proj-ab/models/file-not-covered.py
```

**Requirements:**
On these examples I'm using requirements: `pytest==4.6.2` and `pytest-cov==2.7.1`

Comment: I find this comment useful on my end, as I am searching for ways to resolve my pytest-cov usage on my unit tests. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and the above answers did not fully solve it. It turns out you need to have `__init__.py` was in **every subdirectory** that has a test.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to use 'source' in your `.coveragerc`, you can write as below

```
[run]
source = src
omit = *migrations*, *tests*
plugins = django_coverage_plugin
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue because I ran `pip install .`. Because the package name and the code directory had the same name **and** are in the current directory, coverage probably picked up the directory, while the code that was run was from `site-package` (or visa versa). `pip install -e .` made sure there was no confusion.

Comment: I don't have exactly the same setup, but found that "pip install -e ." was necessary to get coverage to work again. We usually don't install with "-e" in our Ci/CD pipelines so this is a pain.

Comment: I had this problem for some reason when I went back to an old project. Not sure what had happened, but running pip install -e fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error with tox:

```
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

My configuration performs an install of the module and tests that rather than the source code. However, test discovery was finding a module that I had named `test_*.py` in my app package, causing `PYTHONPATH` confusion and resulting in failure to collect coverage details. Renaming the module to not start with `test_` resolved the issue.

Comment: I had to unset my `source` setting under `[tool.coverage.run]` in `pyproject.toml`. Trying to set a bunch of explicit settings isn't always helpful, it seems...

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me: remove "execute" permission from all the *.py files in the scope of the run.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `setup.cfg` or other ways to implicitely pass flags to `pytest`

```
coverage run -m pytest tests
```

won't work if `pytest` receives `--cov-*` flags which basically tell it to generate report itself. Data will be intercepted and `coverage` will be left with nothing.

We've got this error when we changed tooling and CI/CD scripts. So it might be worth checking if you've recently done the same.

Answer (score 0):

I already had `__init__.py` where necessary .

I am not sure why it worked but i simply did:

```
coverage run --omit='*/venv/*' manage.py test
```

and then:

```
coverage html
```

again and I got my intended result

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error when using a standard package layout with `tox`. Turns out there is a [tox bug](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/950#issuecomment-595675051), which necessitates the `tox.ini` testenv config `usedevelop = true`.

**Working example**

layout

```
.
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
├── tests
│   └── test_module.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── pytest.ini
├── .coveragerc
└── tox.ini
```

tox.ini

```ini
[tox]
verbose = true
min_version = 4.0.0
envlist = py38
isolated_build = true
skip_missing_interpreters = true

[testenv:py38]
extras = dev
usedevelop = true
commands =
  pytest -vvv {posargs}
```

pytest.ini

```ini
[pytest]
testpaths =
    tests
addopts =
    --cov=mypackage
    --cov-report=xml
    --log-cli-level=ERROR
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
    ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning
```

.coveragerc

```ini
[run]
source = mypackage
omit =
    venv/*

[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    def __repr__
    raise NotImplementedError
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
poetry config --list
poetry run coverage run
```

And it fixed the "No Data was collected" warning.
[Just adding the poetry config --list line before actually running coverage].