# Jenkins : Coverage.py warning: No data was collected

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, coverage.py

Here's my .coveragerc
`include = */<project-dir>/*`

My sample script:

```
echo "Running unit tests along with coverage"
coverage run -m pytest
echo "printing coverage report"
ls -al
echo "getting coverage report"
coverage report --debug=trace 
exitCode=$?
```

This works fine locally however in Jenkins, I'm seeing this error

`Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)`

I can see Once `coverage run -m pytest` is run, `.coverage` file is created.

I'm confused since .coverage file exists, why is
`coverage report` having trouble finding data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287721/coverage-py-warning-no-data-was-collected-no-data-collected)

Answer (score 1):

In my .coveragerc file, I had both options included which was conflicting.

## Only measure the coverage of files with the following patterns

include = `*/<project_root>/*`

## Don't measure the coverage of files with the following patterns

omit = `*/<project_root>/<folder_name>/*`

Once I removed include, the report started showing up.